# How to save the Future object generated by hyper::Server::with_graceful_shutdown()?

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-axum

When I was using the `hyper` server, I wanted to be able to shut it down gracefully. So I was using `with_graceful_shutdown()` to get a `Future`.

The following code works fine.

```rust
    let signer = Arc::new(Notify::new());
    let waiter = signer.clone();
    let graceful = server.with_graceful_shutdown(waiter.notified());
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        time.sleep(ONE_SEC).await;
        signer.notify_one();
    });
    graceful.await
```

But now I want to save the `graceful` variable above into a structure so that I can easily call .await at the right time to start the server, instead of starting it directly in this function.

However, I so want to have a hard time writing the exact type of `graceful`. Can someone help me?

Comment: `Box<dyn Future>` may be the simplest option.

Comment: Thank you @PitaJ ,but it looks more complicated than expected. There is a ticket talking about it: https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/2582